# react-native firebase child

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I started to create application on react-native and I am trying to do the same thing as I did in android studio application.

[image]

but I cannot do this but I get this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
     let a = database.ref(this.state.date);
     a.child("asd").push("name");
```

but instead of "asd", I am trying to make it random and under this random, it would have key "score" and "name".

Comment: i think you are trying todo a.push({"name":"asd"}}

Comment: Thank you very much! I struggled with this for so long